# При переворачивании телефона создаются два одинкаовых фрагмента

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, recyclerview

У меня есть список музеев, работающий с помощью фрагментов. Приложение запускается, вызывается фрагмент со списком, всё работает хорошо.

[Вертикальная ориентация](https://pp.userapi.com/c846219/v846219528/45757/iGpRKvRz-9w.jpg)

Но когда я переворачиваю телефон, то в отступах между элементами списка видны части его дубликата.

[Горизонтальная ориентация](https://pp.userapi.com/c846219/v846219528/4575e/AwqiWV8gGa8.jpg)

Как это исправить?

Код вызова фрагмента прикрепляю ниже:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.placeholder, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: При повороте экрана активити перезапускается и ваш add срабатывает при каждом повороте. Попробуйте replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FragmentManager запоминает добавленные фрагменты! Фрагмент достаточно добавить один раз при первом запуске активити!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
       ListFragment fragment = new ListFragment();
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
       fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.placeholder, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Поворот экрана обычно разделяют на разные разметки.
отдельно портрет от ландшафт. При повороте экрана происходит обновление процедуры, без обновления экрана.
Вот статейка прочитайте http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/orientation.php